# IInputStream.ReadAsync() and DataReader.LoadAsync() only work for fixed length reads (UWP C#)

Tags: c#, uwp

I'm communicating with a serial device and I want to be able to read data as it comes in the stream. The incoming data will not be of fixed length. However, the aforementioned functions only return a value when "count" number of bytes have been received. According to the documentation, it should return when any number of bytes have been received and load up "count" number of bytes into the intermediate buffer to read.

```
IInputStream stream = EventHandlerForDevice.Current.Device.InputStream;
var buffer = new Byte[100];
IBuffer bufferResult = await stream.ReadAsync(
    buffer.AsBuffer(),
    (uint)buffer.Length,
    InputStreamOptions.Partial).AsTask().ConfigureAwait(false);

buffer = bufferResult.ToArray();
if (bufferResult.Length == 0)
{
    LoggingServices.Instance.WriteLine<App>("something ", LogLevel.Info);
}
```

or

```
DataReaderObject.InputStreamOptions = InputStreamOptions.Partial;
bytesRead = await DataReaderObject.LoadAsync(ReadBufferLength);
```

Both of these only return when the buffer length number of bytes have been received. Otherwise it only works when I pass a count of 1 and handle the input on every byte.

Comment: Well, how many bytes do you want at once?  It's just a buffer size, you can set it to something larger. Not sure I completely grok the question.

Comment: I want to read up to n bytes. The problem is that if I pass a count of n bytes, it won't return until n bytes are received. However, I want it to return if at least 1 byte is received. It's supposed to return as soon as any bytes are available. In the UWP example, they read a file and the last read is less than the the count they pass in. That's the behavior I want. The stream is a different type though.